# Error: "Router must be defined in href" stenciljs router-v2 testing

Tags: typescript, jestjs, href, router, stenciljs

I am trying to test a stencil component.
I use "stencil-router-v2".
I have a link in my component's render method with "href" function:
`` <a {...href(`/news/${this.page}`)} class="btn btn--primary btn--medium btn--view">View</a> ``
When I try to test it, I see the next error: "Router must be defined in href".
Can you please explain to me how to test the "href" function correctly? What test code do I need to write in order for the test to pass?

My component code:

```
import { Component, h, Prop, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';
import { href } from 'stencil-router-v2';
import state from '../store/store';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-news-page',
  styleUrl: 'my-news-page.scss'
})

export class MyNewsPage {  
  @Prop() page: string;
  @Prop() news;

  @Event() newsDeleted: EventEmitter;

  deleteNewsHandler = id => {
    this.newsDeleted.emit(id);
  }

  componentWillRender() {
    this.news = state.newsList.find(news => news.id === +this.page);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <h3>{this.news.title}</h3>
        <p>{this.news.body}</p>
        <button class="btn btn--primary btn--medium btn--delete" onClick={() => this.deleteNewsHandler(this.news.id)}>Delete</button>
        <a {...href(`/news/${this.page}`)} class="btn btn--primary btn--medium btn--view">View</a>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

My test code:

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { MyNewsPage } from '../my-news-page';
import state from '../../store/store';

state.newsList = [
  { id: 1, title: 'title1', body: 'content1' },
  { id: 2, title: 'title2', body: 'content2' },
  { id: 3, title: 'title3', body: 'content3' }
];

const ID = '1';

describe('my-news-page', () => {
  it('should display remaining items', () => {
    let page = new MyNewsPage();
    page.news = state.newsList;
    expect(page.news.length).toEqual(3);
  });

  it('renders', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyNewsPage],
      html: '<div></div>'
    });
    let cmp = page.doc.createElement('my-news-page');
    (cmp as any).page = ID;
    (cmp as any).news = state.newsList.find(news => news.id === +cmp.page);
    page.root.appendChild(cmp);
    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(page.root).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Terminal:

````
  my-news-page
    ✓ should display remaining items (7 ms)
    ✕ renders (37 ms)

  ● my-news-page › renders

    Router must be defined in href

      28 |         <p>{this.news.body}</p>
      29 |         <button class="btn btn--primary btn--medium btn--delete" onClick={() => this.deleteNewsHandler(this.news.id)}>Delete</button>
    > 30 |         {<a {...href(`/news/${this.page}`)} class="btn btn--primary btn--medium btn--view">View</a>}
         |                 ^
      31 |       </section>
      32 |     )
      33 |   }

      at Object.href (node_modules/stencil-router-v2/dist/index.js:106:15)
      at MyNewsPage.render (src/components/my-news-page/my-news-page.tsx:30:17)
      at callRender (node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:421:46)
      at updateComponent (node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:402:247)
      at node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:397:22
      at then (node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:459:47)
      at dispatchHooks (node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:397:7)
      at a (node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:387:18)
      at a (node_modules/@stencil/core/internal/testing/index.js:25:17)```
````

Comment: I haven't looked at this router yet but [from the source](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-router-v2/blob/5815a1892e0e74ba52cadc0defda0afe0e5b7c33/src/router.ts#L411) it looks like you don't have a router defined. Not sure how to do that in tests though. Maybe just call `createRouter` in the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242317/thomas) and [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897426/simon-h%C3%A4nisch), I found the solution.

I should add `const Router = createRouter();` to my code here:

```
import { createRouter } from 'stencil-router-v2';
import { MyNewsPage } from '../my-news-page';
import state from '../../store/store';

state.newsList = [
  { id: 1, title: 'title1', body: 'content1' },
  { id: 2, title: 'title2', body: 'content2' },
  { id: 3, title: 'title3', body: 'content3' }
];

const ID = '1';

describe('my-news-page', () => {
  it('should display remaining items', () => {
    let page = new MyNewsPage();
    page.news = state.newsList;
    expect(page.news.length).toEqual(3);
  });

  it('renders', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyNewsPage],
      html: '<div></div>'
    });
    const Router = createRouter();
    let cmp = page.doc.createElement('my-news-page');
    (cmp as any).page = ID;
    (cmp as any).news = state.newsList.find(news => news.id === +cmp.page);
    page.root.appendChild(cmp);

    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(page.root).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Now my test is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to create a router, then use the `template` option for the spec page (you'll also have to change the test file's extension to `.tsx` and import `h`):

```
import { Fragment, h, newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { createRouter } from 'stencil-router-v2';

const Router = createRouter();

// ...

describe('my-news-page', () => {
  it('renders', async () => {
    const page = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyNewsPage],
      template: () => (
        <Fragment>
          <Router>
            {/* You might have to define routes here, so probably
                best to import your app's router instead. */}
          </Router>

          <my-news-page
            page={ID}
            news={state.newsList.find(news +> news.id === ID)
          />
        </Fragment>
      ),
    });

    await page.waitForChanges();
    expect(page.root).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Using `template` also simplifies setting your props etc. Be aware that this needs to be a **function** returning JSX. `Fragment` is only available in newer Stencil versions afaik.